# Add buttons to Mathjax dialog and update preview area automtically

Tags: ckeditor, mouseevent, keyboard-events, mathjax

I would like to add symbol buttons for `Mathjax` dialog (symbol buttons are not available for default Mathjax plugin).

[image]

As per above image, I have depicted two buttons called `Alpha` and `Beta`.

I would like to achieve functionality that whenever user clicks on these buttons a code should be written, like `\alpha`, in `textarea` and its `preview` should be instantly shown just underneath of `textarea`.

I am able to add Mathjax code to textarea, `\alpha` but its preview is not being displayed on the spot. I have to press any key to see preview.

I have tried with triggering `keyup`, `keydown`, `keypress` etc kind of events on textarea. But no luck.

Can any body help me out to show `preview` automatically as soon as button clicks and text added to text area in `Mathjax dialog`?

I `am not getting exact element` on which keyup or any other keyboard events are being fired. That's why not able to automatically update `Preview` section.

Any help would be heartily appreciated.

Comment: You might want to create a live sample (e.g., on codepen, jsbin etc). Also, have you seen [this example](http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-dynamic.html) ([source](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/blob/master/test/sample-dynamic.html)) ?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger, all those example are working. I am talking about inserting text by clicking button and then show preview without entering code from keyboard in Mathjax dialog.

Comment: Again, an example with what you tried would be good. A wild guess: are you queueing a typeset call after inserting the text? See [the docs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/typeset.html).

Comment: Yes @PeterKrautzberger, I am queuing typeset after inserting text using button click. And what ever I have done is on local so could not show you :(

Comment: Well, I would strongly suggest to re-create a minimal example on a code sharing site; if only to debug your own code. To add to my wild guess: are you sure the typesetting does not fire before the text is actually inserted?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger, yes. Typesetting is not being fired before inserting text into text area from button click.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger, I am not getting exact element on which keyup or any other keyboard events are being fired. That's why not able to automatically update `Preview` section.